# Change BottomNavigationBar index with button press

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigationbar

I have a Bottom Navigation bar like this:

```
Scaffold navBarPages() {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Sends current user to pages.
          PageOne(),
          PageTwo(),
          PageThree(),
          PageFour(),
          PageFive(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        currentIndex: pageIndex,
        onTap: onTap,
        activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem()
          ...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

On PageFive(), I'm performing an action with a button press and I want to pop the screen to PageOne().  `Navigator.pop(context)` returns to PageFive(), dismissing the screen which has the button.

I tried using routes on my main, and then pushing to '/pageOne' namedRoute. But then pageOne doesn't appear with the BottomNavBar and the screen I want to dismiss is still under in the widget tree. I'd like to pop it completely, kinda redirecting the user to the first page.

**Update:**
Using pushAndRemove with a route work:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
'/pageOne', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

The problem I had with routes was that the BottomNavBar wouldn't show after the push. But to fix it I changed 
`routes: {'/pageOne': (context) => PageOne()}`
to 
`routes: {'/home': (context) => Home()}`

Home holds the BottomNavBar class, therefore it works to 'reload' the app, redirecting the user to the first page.

Comment: The more conventional method would be to just change the pageIndex variable after you click the button. Is this not an option for you?

Comment: I'd have to use a callback to access pageIndex from another class right? That might be a problem because the page which has the button isn't a child of BottomNavBar. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: The way I would go about it, is through state management methods such as ChangeNotifierProvider or ScopedModel. State management is basically what you use, when you want to use variables across your widgets, without needing to pass it along some widget hierarchy. 

You can read more about it here https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple and here https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Navigator.pop(context)` if you just want to navigate to '/pageOne' and remove all the previous routes you could do something like

```
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      '/pageOne', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to do that, but then the BottomNavBar disappears from pageOne after the push

Comment: Oh I figured a work around, thanks! I'll update my question in case someone runs into the same problem, but I'll accept your answer.